# How to determine if a var is empty and else set a new value in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have column (row[8]). If a cell is empty I want times to be = 0 - else I want the actual value in the cell. I have a few variations over:

```
IF(times<>""){times==(row[8])} ELSE {(times=="0")}
IF(times==""){times==(row[8])} ELSE {(times=="0")}
IF(times=="NULL"){times==(row[8])} ELSE {(times=="0")}
```

What is the correct syntax?

```
function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = '....';
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; 
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[0]);
    var title = row[1];
    var tstart = setTimeToDate(date,row[2]);
    var tstop = setTimeToDate(date,row[3]);
    Logger.log('date = '+date+'tstart = '+tstart+'  tstop = '+tstop);
    var loc = row[4]; 
    var desc = row[5];
    var type = row[6];
    var NewWeekday = row[7];
    var times = row[8]   
    var id = row[9];      
    var enddate = new Date(row[10]);
```

Comment: Where and how is this `times` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`times=(row[8])?row[8]:0;`

try this:

```
function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  
  var range=sheet.getDataRange();
  var data=range.getValues();
  var calId = '....';
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[0]);
    var title = row[1];
    var tstart = setTimeToDate(date,row[2]);
    var tstop = setTimeToDate(date,row[3]);
    var loc = row[4]; 
    var desc = row[5];
    var type = row[6];
    var NewWeekday = row[7];
    var times = row[8]   
    var id = row[9];      
    var enddate = new Date(row[10]);
```

Comment: times=(row[8])?row[8]:0; seems to work as I don't get red warnings longer. Thank You.

Comment: Your other suggestions called this: Exception: "" can not be converted to  java.lang.Integer.

Comment: In order to assist you further I'd need enough of the code to be able to generate the error myself and also I'd need an image of the sheets involved.

Answer (score 2):

- `IF...ELSE`: There's no such construct in JavaScript. It should be `if...else`
- Empty cell in Google sheets is returned as a empty string `""` , when retrieving values using `getValues`
- `==` is comparison operator and `=` is assignment operator
- To change empty string to 0, use

  ```
  if(times === "") times = 0;
  ```